# how to place two columns side by side in MySql without merging them into one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to place two columns side by side in MySql without merging them into one column.

For example -> 
Input 1:

```
select empName A from tableA where role='X';
```

Output:

```
A
Rahul
Sandeep
Shishir
```

Input 2:

```
select empName B from tableA where role='Y';
```

Output:

```
B
Suresh
Vinay
Ravindra
```

I want my final output as:

```
  A       B 
Rahul   Suresh
Sandeep Vinay
Shishir Ravindra
```

Please note that Table is same in both queries.

Any sql query to achieve my desired output ?

---

Let me further clarify the above scenerio :

Table A contain below data:

Employee_Name   Role
Jordan           X
Ricky            Y 
Sachin           Z
Sourabh          Z
Anil             X

I want my output as :

X         Y       Z
Jordan  Ricky   Sachin
Anil            Sourabh

Hope this remove every doubt with the question.

Comment: How should the processor decide which `Y` employee to associated to each `X` employee? and what if there are not the same number of each?

Comment: Gordon I have not changed the question buddy

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question is:

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when role = 'X' then empName end) as X,
       max(case when role = 'Y' then empName end) as Y      
from tableA;
```

EDIT:

The answer to the updated question requires variables:

```
select max(x) as x, max(y) as y
from ((select empName as x, '' as y, (@xrn := @xrn + 1) as rn
       from tableA cross join (select @xrn := 0) params
       where role = 'X'
      ) union all
      (select '', empName, (@yrn := @yrn + 1) as rn
       from tableA cross join (select yxrn := 0) params
       where role = 'Y'
      )
     ) xy
group by rn;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's not correctly formatted bit Ravindra is in required output

Answer (score 0):

How can the processor know which `Y` employee goes with which `X` employee? You will get a Cartesian product will multiple redundant rows, not what you want. But, if that is ok, then just use a self-Join:

```
select a.empName A, b,empName B
from tableA a
  cross join tableA b
where a.role='X'
  and b.role = 'Y'
```

To get what you want, you need to specify how the `X` employees should be associated with the `Y` employees. Just as they sort alphabetically (... not what your desired output does ...)? or how?

Comment: I have two columns Employee names and Roles and i want to get output where Column names will be displayed as distinct Roles and contain corresponding employee names for that Role. I need to know how to make sql query for this .

Comment: there is no association between role X and Role Y . If there are 5 employees with role X and 3 employees with role Y then in output from the above query I am getting under  8 Employee name under Role X such as  after Fifth Employee the 1st 2nd 3rd employees are repeated and same goes for Role Y too repeated after every 3rd employee till total count becomes 8.

Comment: The output should contain 5 employees under Role X and 3 Employees under Role Y .. is it possible to get this output ?

Comment: There IS an association between Employees in the role X and Employees in role Y.  Specifically, you have `Rahul` associated with `Suresh`, `Sandeep` `associated with Vinay`, and `Shishir` associated with `Ravindra`. Whyat drives that association? Why isn't it, for example, `Rahul` with `Ravindra`?